# Operator overloading c++ (<<)

Tags: c++, dictionary, operator-overloading

This the below program i have written for some test.

```
class tgsetmap
{
public:
std::map<std::string,std::string> tgsetlist;
void operator<<(const char *str1,const char *str2)
{
  tgsetlist.insert( std::map<std::string,std::string>::value_type(str1,str2));
}

};


int main()
{

tgsetmap obj;

obj<<("tgset10","mystring");

obj.tgsetlist.size();
}
```

This throws a compilation error:

*"test.cc", line 10: Error: Illegal number of arguments for tgsetmap::operator<<(const char*, const char*).
"test.cc", line 22: Error: The operation "tgsetmap << const char*" is illegal.
2 Error(s) detected.*

Am i wrong some where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't force `operator<<` to take two arguments on right-hand side. The following code:

```
obj<<("tgset10","mystring");
```

does not work as a function call with two arguments but instead just uses the `,` operator. But it's probably not what you are interested in.

If you need to pass two arguments to the `<<` operator, you need to wrap them in some other (single) type. For example, you could use the standard [std::pair](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/pair/), i.e. `std::pair<const char*, const char*>`.

But note that the `operator<<` should also return some reasonable type suitable for `<<` chaining. That would probably be a `tgsetmap&` in your case. The following version should work fine:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class tgsetmap
{
public:
    typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> list_type;
    typedef list_type::value_type item_type;

    list_type tgsetlist;

    tgsetmap& operator<<(item_type item)
    {
        tgsetlist.insert(item);
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    tgsetmap obj;

    obj << tgsetmap::item_type("tgset10","mystring")
        << tgsetmap::item_type("tgset20","anotherstring");

    std::cout << obj.tgsetlist.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Note that I've added typedefs to not have to repeat the type names over and over again. I've also made `operator<<` return a `tgsetmap&` so that `<<` could be chained (used like in the modified `main()` above). And finally, I've reused the `std::map<...>::value_type` to make it simpler but you could also use any other type of your own.

---

But I believe that you may prefer using a regular method instead. Something like:

```
void add(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    tgsetlist.insert( std::map<std::string, std::string>::value_type(str1, str2));
}
```

(inside the class declaration), and then:

```
obj.add("tgset10", "mystring");
```

Comment: I do know this but i wanted to use the stream operator here.Not so interesting solution  for me.

Comment: Thanks Michal.Learned a new thing :)

Comment: No problem. Feel free to ask if you are not sure about something; I was not sure how deeply to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

The `operator<<` inside of a class must be overloaded like this:

```
T T::operator <<(const T& b) const;
```

If you want to overload it with 2 arguments, you can do it outside of a class:

```
T operator <<(const T& a, const T& b);
```

My compiler, for example, gives a more detailed error message for the code you posted:
[image]

If you are not sure about an operator overloading syntax, there is a [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++) about it.

Comment: need to clear this knowledge, please, add link to the same question or any C++ good book

Comment: Here you can find a book: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: In both the cases, the << will take two args - `a<<b` a is first and b is second. In case you ve declared inside the class, the first arg is the implicit this. So in any case, you cannot make the operator to take more than two args. However you can do this `a<<b<<c`. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. operator << is binary operator. not ternary. not forget about this pointer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the `<<` is binary operator, so there is no way it can take more than two args(One should be this if you are declaring inside the class or a LHS if you are declaring outside the class). However you can accomplish the same functionality by doing `obj<<"tgset10". <<"mystring";`. But since `<<` is a binary operator, you have to do some hack for this.

For this, I ve assigned a static variable `op_count`, where in I will determine if it is the value or the type. And another static variable `temp_str` to store the previous value across invocations.

```
class tgsetmap
{
    public:
    std::map<std::string,std::string> tgsetlist;

    static int op_count = 0;
    static const char *temp_str;
    tgsetmap& operator<<(const char *str)
    {
        op_count++;
        if (op_count%2 != 0) {
            temp_str = str;
        }
        else {
            tgsetlist.insert( std::map<std::string,std::string>::value_type(temp_str,str));
        }
        return this;
    }
};
```

So you can do

```
int main()
{
    tgsetmap obj;
    obj<<"tgset10"<<"mystring";
    obj.tgsetlist.size();
}
```

Or simply you can embed the value and type in the same string using some separator,

value:type = separator is :

value_type = separator is _.